# PDF on browser error - Java servlet

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, web

I am trying to show a pdf into the browser for a web developped in java, but I'm getting some strange behavior.

First, some code about how I am doing that:

```
(HttpServletResponse res)

ServletOutputStream so = null;
res.setContentType( application/pdf);
res.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
so = res.getOutputStream();
so.write( document);
so.flush();
so.close();
```

When I test it in my local project (with my local db/server), it works fine always, but when I test it into dev-machine (from my local machine), sometimes it works and sometimes no and I got this screen:

[image]

What can be wrong between my local machine and dev-machine?, code is the same, and I am using the same machine to test it (so same IE, adobe reader, etc).

Comment: Somehow the header lines with the content type do not seem to be written. Maybe writing happens before. Or a servlet filter. Getting the response writer. The browser or a dev plugin for the browser might show the actual header lines. For the rest: `res.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=info.pdf");`. I have my doubts on that close().